# Parsing an excel sheet with VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

**Scenario:** In my worksheet I have data in multiple columns on the following format (this is an ASCII generated table to facilitate visualization, the symbols are not on the original spreadsheet):

```
+-------+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------------------------------+----------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+
| Count | Indentifier1  | Identifier2 | Identifier3 | ProductName                      | Location | Type                        | Status                   | RegistryDate   |
+-------+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------------------------------+----------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+
| 1     | azjzjzj3611a  |             |             | Super electric board - high load | SEA      | General                     | Sold out -- Used --      | 4/17/2019 4:19 |
|       |               |             |             |                                  |          |                             |   Good                   |                |
+-------+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------------------------------+----------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+
| 2     | y000zj9y30    |             |             | electric board - low battery     | SEA      | General                     | Sold out -- Used -- Good | 5/12/2015 3:48 |
+-------+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------------------------------+----------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+
| 3     |               |             |             | Super jet-ski 01 Special         | SHORE    | TEST - Utility - Vehicle    |                          |                |
+-------+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------------------------------+----------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+
| 4     | a30y970y3     |             |             | Super jet-ski 01 Special         | SHORE    | TEST - Utility - Vehicle    | Used - Good              |                |
+-------+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------------------------------+----------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+
| 5     |               |             |             | Ball 10-Type1                    | BEACH    | TEST - Utility - Small-Item |                          |                |
+-------+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------------------------------+----------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+
| 6     | azjzjzja9zjy9 |             |             | Ball 10-Type1                    | BEACH    |                             |                          |                |
+-------+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------------------------------+----------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+
| 7     | azjzjzja9zjy9 |             |             | Ball 10-Type1                    | BEACH    | TEST - Utility - Small-Item | Sold out -- Used - Good  | 6/10/2013 0:00 |
+-------+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------------------------------+----------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+
| 8     | a3044aa69     | 1007750     |             | Ball 10-Type1                    |          |                             |                          |                |
+-------+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------------------------------+----------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+
| 9     |               |             |             | Ball 10-Type1                    | BEACH    | TEST - Utility - Small Unit |                          |                |
+-------+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------------------------------+----------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+
| 10    | a3044aa69     |             | BLL101      | Ball 10-Type1                    | BEACH    | TEST - Utility - Small Unit | Used - Good              |                |
+-------+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------------------------------+----------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+
| 11    | a3044aa69     | 1007750     | BLL101      | BALL 10-TYPE1                    | Beach    | TEST - Utility              |                          |                |
+-------+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------------------------------+----------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+
| 12    | y0003aa67     | 36021       |             | Ball 5-Type1                     |          |                             |                          |                |
+-------+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------------------------------+----------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+
| 13    |               |             |             | Ball 5-Type1                     | RIDGE    | Group - Special             |                          |                |
+-------+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------------------------------+----------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+
| 14    | y0003aa67     |             |             | Ball 5-Type1                     | RIDGE    |                             |                          |                |
+-------+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------------------------------+----------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+
| 15    | y0003aa67     |             | BLL051      | Ball 5-Type1                     | RIDGE    | Group - Special             | Used - Good              |                |
+-------+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------------------------------+----------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+
| 16    | y0003aa67     | 36021       | BLL051      | BALL 5-TYPE1                     | Ridge    | Group - Special             |                          |                |
+-------+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------------------------------+----------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+
```

**Obs.:** As per the table, the data can have multiple entries, where different information is displayed in each column. The differences may be either the format (upper/lower-case) or content (has data or not).

**Objective:** I am trying to retrieve the information from this table, without loosing data. Ex: If two rows have the same data, but one is lower case whereas the other is upper case, either could be retrieved (no preference), but if there is different data (maybe there is a slight difference in the item name or status), I am trying to retrieve all the data.

**Done so far:** I was able to simple create an array, loop it, and compare the data manually, but the result is sub-optimal, since it just aggregates the data in the same cell where it is different. Which would still require manual checking/cleaning.

**Obs2.:** This table has around 22 thousand rows.

**Obs3.:** Another issue of this data-set is that none of the columns is completely filled. Sometimes I have data for all identifiers and item name, sometimes an identifier is missing, sometimes the name is missing, and sometimes just one identifier is available (no name or anything else).

**Question:** Is there a way to do this?

**Wanted output:**

```
+-------+--------------+-------------+-------------+------------------------------+----------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+
| Count | Indentifier1 | Identifier2 | Identifier3 | ProductName                  | Location | Type                        | Status                   | RegistryDate   |
+-------+--------------+-------------+-------------+------------------------------+----------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+
| 1     | azjzjzj3611a |             |             | Super electric               | SEA      | General                     | Sold out -- Used --      | 4/17/2019 4:19 |
|       |              |             |             |   board - high load          |          |                             |   Good                   |                |
+-------+--------------+-------------+-------------+------------------------------+----------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+
| 2     | y000zj9y30   |             |             | electric board - low battery | SEA      | General                     | Sold out -- Used -- Good | 5/12/2015 3:48 |
+-------+--------------+-------------+-------------+------------------------------+----------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+
| 3     | a30y970y3    |             |             | Super jet-ski 01 Special     | SHORE    | TEST - Utility - Vehicle    | Used - Good              |                |
+-------+--------------+-------------+-------------+------------------------------+----------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+
| 4     | a3044aa69    | 1007750     |             | Ball 10-Type2                | BEACH    | TEST - Utility - Small-Item | Sold out -- Used - Good  | 6/10/2013 0:00 |
+-------+--------------+-------------+-------------+------------------------------+----------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+
| 5     | a3044aa69    | 1007750     | BLL101      | Ball 10-Type1                | BEACH    | TEST - Utility - Small Unit | Used - Good              |                |
+-------+--------------+-------------+-------------+------------------------------+----------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+
| 6     | y0003aa67    | 36021       | BLL051      | BALL 5-TYPE1                 | Ridge    | Group - Special             | Used - Good              |                |
+-------+--------------+-------------+-------------+------------------------------+----------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+
```

**Code for array approach:**

```
Sub cleanup_detail()

Dim raw_array As Variant
Dim w As Workbook
Dim loopvar1 As Long

Set w = ThisWorkbook

raw_array = w.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange

For loopvar1 = 2 To UBound(raw_array, 1)
    If raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 2) = "" Or raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 2) = "0" Then
        If raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 3) = "" Or raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 3) = "0" Then
            If raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 4) = "" Or raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 4) = "0" Then
                If raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 5) = "" Or raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 5) = "0" Then
                    Next loopvar1
                ElseIf raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 5) = raw_array(loopvar1, 5) Then
                    w.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(loopvar1 + 1, 2) = raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 2) & "/" & raw_array(loopvar1, 2)
                    w.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(loopvar1 + 1, 3) = raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 3) & "/" & raw_array(loopvar1, 3)
                    w.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(loopvar1 + 1, 3) = raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 4) & "/" & raw_array(loopvar1, 4)
                    w.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(loopvar1 + 1, 3) = raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 5)
                    w.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(loopvar1 + 1, 3) = raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 6) & "/" & raw_array(loopvar1, 6)
                    w.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(loopvar1 + 1, 3) = raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 7) & "/" & raw_array(loopvar1, 7)
                    w.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(loopvar1 + 1, 3) = raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 8) & "/" & raw_array(loopvar1, 8)
                    w.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(loopvar1 + 1, 3) = raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 9) & "/" & raw_array(loopvar1, 9)
                End If
            ElseIf raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 4) = raw_array(loopvar1, 4) Then
                w.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(loopvar1 + 1, 2) = raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 2) & "/" & raw_array(loopvar1, 2)
                w.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(loopvar1 + 1, 3) = raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 3) & "/" & raw_array(loopvar1, 3)
                w.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(loopvar1 + 1, 3) = raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 4)
                w.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(loopvar1 + 1, 3) = raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 5) & "/" & raw_array(loopvar1, 5)
                w.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(loopvar1 + 1, 3) = raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 6) & "/" & raw_array(loopvar1, 6)
                w.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(loopvar1 + 1, 3) = raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 7) & "/" & raw_array(loopvar1, 7)
                w.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(loopvar1 + 1, 3) = raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 8) & "/" & raw_array(loopvar1, 8)
                w.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(loopvar1 + 1, 3) = raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 9) & "/" & raw_array(loopvar1, 9)
            End If
        ElseIf raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 3) = raw_array(loopvar1, 3) Then
            w.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(loopvar1 + 1, 2) = raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 2) & "/" & raw_array(loopvar1, 2)
            w.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(loopvar1 + 1, 3) = raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 3) & "/" & raw_array(loopvar1, 3)
            w.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(loopvar1 + 1, 3) = raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 4) & "/" & raw_array(loopvar1, 4)
            w.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(loopvar1 + 1, 3) = raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 5) & "/" & raw_array(loopvar1, 5)
            w.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(loopvar1 + 1, 3) = raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 6) & "/" & raw_array(loopvar1, 6)
            w.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(loopvar1 + 1, 3) = raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 7) & "/" & raw_array(loopvar1, 7)
            w.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(loopvar1 + 1, 3) = raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 8) & "/" & raw_array(loopvar1, 8)
            w.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(loopvar1 + 1, 3) = raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 9) & "/" & raw_array(loopvar1, 9)
        End If
    ElseIf raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 2) = raw_array(loopvar1, 2) Then
        w.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(loopvar1 + 1, 2) = raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 2)
        w.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(loopvar1 + 1, 3) = raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 3) & "/" & raw_array(loopvar1, 3)
        w.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(loopvar1 + 1, 3) = raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 4) & "/" & raw_array(loopvar1, 4)
        w.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(loopvar1 + 1, 3) = raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 5) & "/" & raw_array(loopvar1, 5)
        w.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(loopvar1 + 1, 3) = raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 6) & "/" & raw_array(loopvar1, 6)
        w.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(loopvar1 + 1, 3) = raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 7) & "/" & raw_array(loopvar1, 7)
        w.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(loopvar1 + 1, 3) = raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 8) & "/" & raw_array(loopvar1, 8)
        w.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(loopvar1 + 1, 3) = raw_array(loopvar1 + 1, 9) & "/" & raw_array(loopvar1, 9)
    End If
Next loopvar1

End Sub
```

Comment: So you want to consolidate multiple rows in one row if they have the same data or the sum of the data can be inserted in a single row, multiple rows if your data changes. Identifiers might or might not be. I suppose this data comes sorted, so if no identifier is found in `Identifier1` excel would assume the identifier is the same as the last filled cell on that column.

Comment: @Damian Yes, it is basically consolidating the data for each item in one row with all available information for it (and as you said, if the data is different in two rows, aggregate it into one cell). I could sort the data by any of the columns, but the fact that every column is missing some items makes it confusing on how I should loop the array.

Comment: I mean, for example row 13 on your table has no identifiers, I am (or the macro) to assume that it belongs to the previous identifier?

Comment: @Damian In that case the name would be the last check. It would compare the name of the row and see if it is there. For cases where no identifiers/name are available, then the macro skips the row completely.

Comment: I would approach this with classes, using relations with the identifiers and the product name, to check on every row any of the 4 possibilities, once you know what product is, then check its properties to see if they match or not. If not, then insert another row.